# Primefaces p: tree unchecked checkbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using the component **p:tree** in primefaces with mode selection and would like to uncheck checkbox selected nodes send data once.

```
<h:form id="formtree" styleClass="formsize">
    <p:tree widgetVar="myTree" value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" id="checkboxTree" selectionMode="checkbox"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNodes}" styleClass="formsize">
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="nodestree"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</h:form>
```